# When CAN i break aliasing rules?

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing, type-punning

I get this warning. I would like defined behavior but i would like to keep this code as it is. When may i break aliasing rules?

> warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]

String is my own string which is a POD. This code is called from C. S may be an int. String is pretty much `struct String { RealString*s; }` but templated and helper functions. I do a static assert to make sure String is a pod, is 4bytes and int is 4bytes. I also wrote an assert which checks if all pointers are >= NotAPtr. Its in my new/malloc overload. I may put that assert in String as well if you suggest

Considering the rules i am following (mainly that string is a pod and always the same size as int) would it be fine if i break aliasing rules? Is this one of the few times one is breaking it right?

```
void func(String s) {
    auto v=*(unsigned int*)&s;
    myassert(v);
    if(v < NotAPtr) {
        //v is an int
    }
    else{
        //v is a ptr
    }
}
```

Comment: "How fast can I drive without getting a speeding ticket?" Microsoft did something like this with `MAKEINTRESOURCE`, but they write the compiler too and can add an extension. Ordinary mortals cannot. And in C++ they could have added an overload.

Comment: You're on a slippery slope here. Do you really have a good reason not to make separate func_i and func_s functions?

Comment: @PerJohansson: I did at the beginning of the project. Now that reason doesn't exist anymore. So I made 2 functions instead. +1

Comment: It's never "fine to break aliasing rules", as being UB, it gives the compiler a free ticket to remove or render unrecognisable your entire program. It doesn't matter if we can look at it and say 'yeah, that would work on 99% of platforms with a non-capricious compiler'; such a compiler is not required by the Standard to exist.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The safe way of treating a variable as two different types is to turn it into a union. One part of the union can be your pointer, the other part an integer.

```
struct String
{
    union
    {
        RealString*s;
        int i;
    };
};
```

Comment: Technically union might not work for type punning and if there was a store to `s` read from `i` is undefined (it can be always 0 for example). However in this case there is strict aliasing violation due to strange cast - not due to any 'real' violation hence it is possible to simply cast from pointer to int.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Actually, reading from the member of a `union` other than the last one written is *unspecified* behavior, not *undefined*.

Comment: @james: Can you point to the section in the Standard?  As far as I can tell, reading a non-active member of a union involves (1) a member access expression, which is an lvalue, and (2) an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  Since the object referenced by the lvalue is not an object of the lvalue type (nor any subclass), any such program invokes undefined behavior according to section 4.1 (`[conv.lval]`).

Comment: @BenVoigt you need to remember that this is reading a pointer and is not dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: @acidzombie24: A member access is also an lvalue.  In `String t; t.s = new RealString("literal"); auto v = t.i;`, the final statement requires an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, using a type (int) different from the type of the object that actually exists (RealString*).

Comment: @BenVoigt: I believe all pointers have a conversion to int. I know `(int)some_ptr` does work but i know its reinterpret_cast but not how legal that is.

Comment: @acidzombie24: `reinterpret_cast` from a pointer to an integral type is legal, and will round-trip if the integral type is large enough.  But I can't find anywhere that says reading an inactive member of a union is the same as `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: Me neither. But i was trying to say that is a conversion form ptr to int so it does exist. Its still foggy if this is undefined or not. I am leaning towards the defined side.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Hmm, perhaps I was mixed up with C, where the C99 standard explicitly lists it as unspecified behavior (section J.1).

Comment: Define "safe" and "treating a variable as two different types". If you're implying Standard C++ allows type-punning through `union`s, like C99 does (and which lazy compilers pass on to their C++ frontends), that's utterly false. If - and this is the only interpretation I can make - you mean the OP or anyone in the same situation should use this `union` to reinterpret an `int` from the pointer, i.e. read from a member different than the (active) one last written to - you're advising them to break their code and hope the compiler doesn't find a way to optimise said breakage in an observable way.

Comment: Casting a pointer to a type with 8-bit or 16-bit alignment into a pointer to union that also contains a type with 32-bit alignment yields UB, *and will sometimes fail when compiled by clang for platforms with alignment restrictions*, even if none of the 32-bit types within the union are used in any way.

Answer (score 4):

`memcpy` is fully supported.  So is punning to a `char*` (you can then use `std::copy`, for instance).

Comment: I'm not sure about C++, but certainly in C99 the `memcpy` function is only guaranteed safe for type conversion in cases where the destination operand has a declared type.  The specs go through a lot of trouble to prevent `memcpy` from being safely usable to copy an object of one type to storage without no declared type, for the purpose of accessing it as a different type.

Comment: @supercat: I see that `string.h` has the following rule which therefore applies to `memcpy` -- "Unless explicitly stated otherwise in the description of a particular function in this subclause, pointer arguments on such a call shall still have valid values, as described in 7.1.4."  What exactly in 7.1.4 do you think is a problem here?  And how would you get "storage without a declared type" in the first place?  And why would it matter for the scenario described, which is `int i; memcpy(&i, &s, sizeof i);` ?

Comment: In C99 (and I don't think this changed in C11), given `int x=1234; long *p = malloc(sizeof (long)); *p = 5678; memcpy(p, &x, sizeof x;);` attempting to read `*p` as a `long` will invoke Undefined Behavior even if `int` and `long` have the same representation since the `memcpy` will set the Effective Type of `*p` to `int`.

Comment: The fundamental problem is that for good performance a compiler needs to know what things might be aliased by the source or destination of memcpy and memmove, but the functions were defined at a time when compilers didn't care; consequently, they provide no means of indicating the types.  The problem could have been solved by requiring that those functions presume worst-case aliasing on source and destination, but adding new functions that let the programmer specify whether the source and/or destination types was known, or whether the dest type was known to match an unknown source type.

Comment: Instead, the authors of the Standard bodged `memcpy`/`memmove` so that in cases where the source type is known and the destination type is unknown, a compiler may assume that the destination will be read using the same type that was used earlier to write the source.  That may be helpful in cases where the assumption is correct, but is a *lousy* assumption to let a compiler make given that one of the primary uses of `memcpy` has historically been to perform type punning.

Comment: @supercat: But using `memcpy` for type-punning when there is a declared type is still perfectly allowed, correct?  Also, C++ has none of this "effective type of the object from which the value is copied" nonsense.

Comment: Use of memcpy for type conversion is allowed in cases where the destination has a declared type.  As for C++, it specifies that `memcpy` works the same way it does in C, without explicitly saying how it interacts with the dynamic type of the storage involved, which could be interpreted as making the behavior with regard to C's Effective Type applicable to C++'s Dynamic Type.

Comment: The availability of Placement New fixes a lot of difficulties in C++, though it would be helpful to have means of indicating whether a programmer needs to regard storage as having whatever pattern of bits it received (by whatever means) before the Placement New, or whether the programmer is willing to accept that the Storage may hold Unspecified Value, a non-contagious Indeterminate Value (repeated reads yield independent Unspecified values), or a contagious non-trapping Indeterminate Value (a read yields Indeterminate Value), or a possibly-trapping IV (a read would yield UB).

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change code to 2 functions as proposed why not (requires C99 compiler as uses `uintptr_t` - for older MSVC you need to define it yourself, 2008/2010 should be ok):

```
void f(RealString *s) {
    uintptr_t int = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(s);
    assert(int);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Standard specifies a minimal set of actions that all conforming implementations must process in predictable fashion unless they encounter translation limits (whereupon all bets are off).  It does not attempt to define all of the actions that an implementation must support to be suitable for any particular purpose.  Instead, support for actions beyond those mandated is treated as a Quality of Implementation issue.  The authors acknowledge that an implementation could be conforming and yet be of such poor quality as to be useless.

Code such as yours should be usable for quality implementations that are intended for low-level programming, and which represent things in memory in the expected fashion.  It should not be expected to be usable on other kinds of implementations, including those which interpret "quality of implementation" issues as an invitation to try to behave in poor-quality-but-conforming fashion.